# Starting Problem

Tags: honda, civic, starter

I have a 2002 Honda Civic LX 1.7 Engine. It won't turn over, the battery is new and all indicator lights work. It starts with Bum start but not on its own.Any sugestions would be appreciated.

Thanks; Carl

Comment: What do you mean by "Bum start"?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I think he means "bump" start.

Comment: My first guess is that the starter is bad.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 it's when a homeless person pushes your car to start it.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Make sure the car is in park or neutral with the parking brake on and apply power to the S terminal on the starter. This will tell you if it's the starter or not.

If the engine turns over the fault is either in the transmission range switch/clutch safety switch, the starter relay, fuse or ignition switch.